# How retrieve old value in class (PHP)?

Tags: php

I want have 2 variables with same value (my class), and i want to keep values when I update values in one of two variables.

```
$var1 = new Class(['name' => 'Jeff Bezos']);
$var2 = $var1;
$var1->updateMyObject(['name' => 'Elon Musk']);
```

but now my $var2 have Elon Musk passed in my class.

Do I necessarily have two separate instances of my class ?

Comment: *"Do I necessarily have two separate instances of my class ?"* Yes, `$var2 = $var1;` both variables are pointing to the same element in the heap memory

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valentin you should clone **objects**, otherwise the object is referenced

```php
$var1 = new Class(['name' => 'Jeff Bezos']);
$var2 = clone $var1;
$var1->updateMyObject(['name' => 'Elon Musk']);
```

Comment: For simple types this is not the case, e.g. strings
```php
$var1 = 'Jeff Bezos';
$var2 = $var1;
$var1 = 'Elon Musk';
```
works just fine